# in-code checking of perl switches

Tags: perl, command-line, command-line-arguments

Is there any way to check whitch of perl command line switches have been activated ?
For instance if I run my program like `perl -C foo.pl`, I would like to be able to check whether the -C switch has been activated or not.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) manpage:

> The -C flag controls some of the Perl Unicode features.... The
>   read-only magic variable `${^UNICODE}` reflects the numeric value of
>   this setting. This variable is set during Perl startup and is
>   thereafter read-only.

There are other magic variables for some other commandline switches. Either perlrun or perlvar should have the information you seek.